# Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ real-valued matrix. Given a vector $v$ in $\mathbb R^3 \ldots$

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I am having a very hard time thinking of how to even start this problem:

Let $A$ be a $3\times3$ real-valued matrix.  Given a vector $v$ in $\mathbb R^3$, consider the $3\times4$ matrix $B$, defined in terms of columns as $B =[v \space Av \space  A^2v \space A^3v]$.

Describe all the possible configurations of leading ones in the reduced row echelon form for $B$.  (Consider the various ways that a Krylov sequence of vectors can become linearly dependent.)

Answer (score 0):

If $v$ and $Av$ are linearly dependent, then $Av$ and $A^2v$ are also linearly dependent, for example.

Let $C=rref (B)$. Then if $v=0$, $C=0$. Otherwise, first column of $C$ is $(1,0,0) $ and the $A^3v $ will be a linear combination of the previous ones so last column of $C$ is zero (reason as in the first sentence of this post and the fact that 4 vectors cannot be linearly independent in a space of dimension 3). The second column of $C$ could be zero or not, depending on $A,v$. However, if it is zero, then so are the remaining columns (again see starting remark). If it is non-zero, then the third again could be zero or not. The fourth one is zero as explained earlier.

So you can then do this sort of reasoning to answer the question.