# Krylov sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Directions: Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ real valued matrix. Given $v$ in $V (\mathbb{R^3})$, consider the $3 \times 4$ matrix $B$, defined in terms of $B = [v \  \  Av \ \  A^2v \ \   A^3v]$.
Describe all possible configurations of leading ones in row echelon form for $B$. (Consider the various ways that a Krylov sequence of vectors can become linearly independent)

I'm confused on how to think about this problem. I have very limited knowledge about Krylov sequences, but I understand that the vectors will most likely become linearly dependent due to power iterative. Is the goal to find possible eigenvalues? I wrote down a few matrices that have leading ones in different places, but I'm not sure what to do with them. If someone could provide an example I would appreciate it!

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2244313/265466.